# ReferenceManyInput in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, components, react-admin

In react-admin we have [ReferenceManyField](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ReferenceManyField.html). It would be fantastic to have also a component called ReferenceManyInput, with a functionallity very similar to the [ArrayInput](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/ArrayInput.html) component (add, remove buttons) but with reference to a resource.

¿Does any one know if they have intention to include it or is there any workaround to achieve this?

The use case is:

I have a form for creating/editing an entity where one of its properties is an array of other related entities. I would like to add and/or remove new elements to that array and when submitting the main entity, it creates/updates/remove the related entity and the main entity.

Maybe I am asking for too much...

Thanks in advance

Comment: The react-admin core team is currently working on such an input. Stay tuned for a release within a week or two.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck: `<ReferenceManyInput>` was just published as part of React-admin Enterprise Edition. It works just like `ReferenceManyField`:

```
import {
    Edit,
    SimpleForm,
    TextInput,
    NumberInput,
    ReferenceInput,
    SelectInput,
} from 'react-admin';
import { ReferenceManyInput } from '@react-admin/ra-relationships';

const ProductEdit = () => (
    <Edit mutationMode="optimistic">
        <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput source="name" />
            <NumberInput source="price" />
            <ReferenceInput source="category_id" reference="categories" />
            <ReferenceManyInput reference="variants" target="product_id">
                <SimpleFormIterator inline>
                    <TextInput source="sku" />
                    <SelectInput source="size" choices={sizes} />
                    <SelectInput source="color" choices={colors} />
                    <NumberInput source="stock" defaultValue={0} />
                </SimpleFormIterator>
            </ReferenceManyInput>
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

The result looks like:

[image: ReferenceManyInput]

Check https://marmelab.com/ra-enterprise/modules/ra-relationships#referencemanyinput for details.